# Making a subvector, that only keeps elements divisible by three

Tags: r, vector

so I am currently struggling with starting out in R. I had a task of creating a vector `v=c(1,3,5,7,8,9,11,13,15,17,19,21)`, and then to create a subvector, that only keeps the elements of `v` that are divisible by three.

I suppose i would have to use the `%%` operator but I am not really sure how to get it to kind of pick and choose, instead of just dividing every element by three. I also tried to create a vector of just threes in order to the divide the original vector by that... no suprise that didnt work lol.

Any help appreciated, i just want to get to know how to use the different operators and commands.

Comment: `newv <- v[ v %% 3 == 0 ]`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The above can be read as `v[`, a truth test `v %% 3 == 0`, which ones divide evenly by 3, `]`, you can send that to a new variable `<-`, or not (prints to screen), check you math intuitions with `%% 3 ==2`. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

##### Create vector

```
   x <- c(1,3,5,7,8,9,11,13,15,17,19,21)
```

##### Filter elements that can divided by 3

```
x[(x %% 3) == 0]
```

##### Result

```
[1]  3  9 15 21
```

Comment: I am glad it helped you @OscarColt, if could "close" the question, here is a tutorial for best practices: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `keep` only the elements divisable by 3, you can do it with `purrr::keep` and modulo `x%%y`.

```
library(purrr)

v %>% keep(v%%3==0)

#OR simply

keep(v, v%%3==0)

[1]  3  9 15 21
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to use this solution, but i had a bit of trouble getting the library(purrr) to work, but I'm trying to figure it out, so that i can learn to use this solution as well.